# Exception inside block causing unusual behavior of logic

Tags: c#, exception, azure

Bear with me as this might be difficult to explain (but fret not, I have screencasts just for this!).

We are running an Azure worker process which processes messages from a queue.  Azure picks up the message and starts handling the logic.

During execution, we go to the database and grab a log record (using EF, not lazy as it returns a full object).  The very next step is to validate that the object is not null.

```
var log = Repo.Find(fileId);
if (log == null)
{
```

The object is not null.  The expression evaluates to false.  Hovering over the `==` in Visual Studio shows that the expression is false.  Running this code in the Immediate Window will show that the evaluation is false.  The code should NOT step into the `if` block.

Notice I said "should not".

Inside the if block we are throwing an exception. For some reason, even though the expression evaluates to false, the exception is thrown.  It doesn't matter what type of exception, either, since I tried two different types.

And the final twist is that I remove the exception from the `if` block and perform some other logic, the block is skipped as expected.

So, the following functions as expected:

```
var log = Repo.Find(fileId);
if (log == null)
{
    var x = 1;
}
```

But the code below does not:

```
var log = Repo.Find(fileId);
if (log == null)
{
    var exceptionText = "The specified log could not be found.";
    throw new ArgumentException(exceptionText);
}
```

Here are a few screencasts to prove that I'm not crazy (and for a better definition of what's going on)

[Screencast showing exception](http://www.screencast.com/t/kSdZCqDTh46t)

[Screencast showing without exception](http://www.screencast.com/t/mKAwcoqJ5dp)

And just for full disclosure, I also tried this with `log.Equals(null)` with the same result.  Seems all of the variations of the Object.Equals null always returns the same result here (false).

Comment: I'm guessing this is multi-threaded?

Comment: This is not, sorry, should have clarified.  This is synchronous processing.

Comment: What is the object type that returns from `Repo.Find`?  I know you mention that hovering over the `==` says the expression is false but I'm wondering if that object overrides `Equals`.

Comment: Also, if you set a breakpoint at `var exceptionText...` does it get hit?

Comment: The object type is just a plain object, nothing special about it at all (custom POCO).  There is nothing overriding the `Equals` (already checked that).  The exceptionText evaluates to `null` as shown in the first screencast.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, you shouldn't get the exception, but things like this usually happens when someone use 3rd party tools in Visual Studio for AOP (PostSharp etc.). Could you check it? If you use it, try removing attributes and run again this piece of code, I think problem will disappear.

Comment: I would have to agree with this statement.  I haven't had time to try removing all of the various aspects / attributes, but I have a strong suspicion that this is the culprit too.